# Getting bullet points working in wxPython.RichTextControl

Tags: python-2.7, wxpython

I'm making a application with wxPython RichTextCtrl, and I'm currently trying to make bullet points working. I was referencing [this tutorial](http://xoomer.virgilio.it/infinity77/wxPython/richtext/wx.richtext.html) when writing, but it isn't real-time working application, but instead adds text in code.
It looks pretty easy when they do bullet points, but when I try... well this is what I get :

[image: Bullet Points in rich text control]

Here's some of my code:

```
class RichTextEditor(rt.RichTextCtrl): 
def __init__(self, parent): 
    rt.RichTextCtrl.__init__(self, parent, style=wx.VSCROLL|wx.HSCROLL|wx.NO_BORDER|wx.FONTFAMILY_DEFAULT|wx.TEXT_ATTR_FONT_FACE) 

    self.Bind(wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN, self.OnKeyDown)
    self.BallPoint = 0 

def GetHtmlContent(self): 
    # Get an instance of the html file handler, use it to save the 
    # document to a StringIO stream.
def remove_tags(self, text):
    # Clean some unwanted HTML tags

def OnKeyDown(self, evt): 
    keycode = evt.GetKeyCode() 

    if evt.ControlDown(): 
        if (keycode == ord('B') ): 
            self.ApplyBoldToSelection() 
        elif (keycode == ord('I')): 
            self.ApplyItalicToSelection() 
        elif (keycode == ord('U')): 
            self.ApplyUnderlineToSelection()
        elif (keycode == ord('P') and not self.BallPoint):
            self.BeginSymbolBullet('*', 100, 60)
            self.BallPoint = 1
        elif (keycode == ord('P') and self.BallPoint):
            self.EndSymbolBullet()
            self.BallPoint = 0

    evt.Skip()
```

As you can see, there's not much. Control is in a panel, and panel in a frame and that one is displayed in my app. Screen shows you runtime of my app, text describes my actions. Adding `self.EndIntend()` wont work as well.

EDIT:

> The only thing that I can suggest, short of reporting it as a bug, is changing:

```
elif (keycode == ord('P') and not self.BallPoint):
    self.BeginSymbolBullet('*', 100, 60)
    self.BallPoint = 1
```

> to:

```
elif (keycode == ord('P') and not self.BallPoint):
    self.BeginSymbolBullet('*', 100, 60)
    self.BallPoint = 1
    self.Newline()
    self.MoveUp(1)
```

> This adds a line below your bullet which you can access using arrow down.
>   With this method, whilst very unsatisfactory, you no longer require the >self.EndSymbolBullet() and obviously, you won't need to test BallPoint either.

Work around by [Rolf of Saxony](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4637585/rolf-of-saxony)

This is how it works now:[image: Bullet Point revised]

But you know, it's still not it. I will try to contact the dev team for wxPython, as suggested.

EDIT 2... [Rolf of Saxony](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4637585/rolf-of-saxony)
 found a solution... kinda...
Here's how it goes
[image: Kinda working bullet points]

And now's the fun part. I know it is not exactly regular thing to do, but if it can happen, then it will.
[image: Strange behaviour]

(After first delete there's enter) [Rolf of Saxony](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4637585/rolf-of-saxony) solution does solve partway my problem - I can now get rid of bullet points and intend. But it still behaves in unexpected ways. I will try to find out why and how to avoid this kind of situation.

Comment: You have told us what you get, but we are none the wiser as to what it is that you want. Tell us what it is that you want to achieve and then somebody may be able to help.

Comment: Sorry, I should've added I want to make it working PROPERLY. Because clearly we can see that it is not. It even does not work as in that example tutorial I linked in my question.

Comment: To be clear, what is not working is `EndSymbolBullet()` because it does not end bullet point. Instead pressing 'enter' starts new bullet point! I don't want that... And intend stays there, I cannot remove it in any way. I don't want that either.

Answer (score 1):

I have played with your code and I don't seem to be able to get the End???Bullet() to function as you want it to either. It seems that with the style set for the insertion point, there is no way to reset it, although I have tried using the `attr.SetBulletStyle(wx.richtext.TEXT_ATTR_BULLET_STYLE_NONE)` function.
The only thing that I can suggest, short of reporting it as a bug, is changing:

```
elif (keycode == ord('P') and not self.BallPoint):
    self.BeginSymbolBullet('*', 100, 60)
    self.BallPoint = 1
```

to:

```
elif (keycode == ord('P') and not self.BallPoint):
    self.BeginSymbolBullet('*', 100, 60)
    self.BallPoint = 1
    self.Newline()
    self.MoveUp(1)
```

This adds a line below your bullet which you can access using arrow down.
With this method, whilst very unsatisfactory, you no longer require the `self.EndSymbolBullet()` and obviously, you won't need to test BallPoint either.

Sorry, I can't be more help.

Comment: Well, at least you proved that there is a problem, thanks :)
Updating question with your solution

Comment: @PiotrKamoda Use the Delete key to cancel the Bullet

Comment: I can't believe it really works... Well it's still unintuitive as... But now I know it can work, so perhaps I'll meddle a little in events and try to parse backspace in certain situations to behave like it should, but like delete does... And it's still not perfect. I will have to check why something else happens that probably should not (check out latest edit)